# is there another way to join these tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ssms

I wanted to join both tables [Header] and [Line] so as to could fill my fact table on my ssdt and i get this error message that tells i have incorrect syntax for all columns

```sql
select
concat ([Document No_],[Line No_]) as [InterventionLigne],
case H.Status
when 0 then ''
when 1 then 'Non Traité'
when 2 then 'Intervention'
when 3 then 'Rép. en Instance'
when 4 then 'Rép. en cours'
when 5 then 'Liv. en Instance'
when 6 then 'Liv. en cours'
when 7 then 'Email envoyé'
when 8 then 'Pickup Magasin'
when 9 then 'Arrivé a IRC'
when 10 then 'Transfert au CTA'
when 11 then 'Retour du CTA'
when 12 then 'Retour au magasin'
when 13 then 'Livraison'
end as Statut
[No_ Document Externe] as [Num_ Document Externe],
H.[Nom],
H.[Adresse Contact],
H.[Ville],
[Commentaire],
[Sources Réclamations],
[Date Reclamation],
[Designation],
case H.Saved
when 0 then 'Non'
when 1 then 'Oui'
end as Enregist,
case H.Validated
when 0 then 'Non'
when 1 then 'Oui'
end as Validé,
[USER] as [Utilisateur],
case H.[Type Intervention]
when 0 then ''
when 1 then 'Direct'
when 2 then 'Via Un Partenaire'
end as [Type_Intervention],
[Partenaire],[Année garantie], case H.NonEdit
when 0 then 'Non'
when 1 then 'Oui'
end as [NonEdit],
[Magasin],[Emplacement],[En Garantie],[Job No_],[Document No_] as [Document Num_],
[Line No_] as[Line Num_],
[Type Travaux],[Starting Date] as [DateDébut],
[Travaux effectués],
[Libellé],
l.[technicien],
[Remarque],
[Rémunération]
from [dbo].[Header$] H left join [dbo].[Line$] L
on H.[No_ Document]=L.[Document No_]
```

> errors: Syntaxe incorrecte vers 'No_ Document Externe'

and I get the same error for all columns.

Comment: You have `case H.Status ...  end as Statut ` You need a comma after the alias name. Honestly, if you format your code so that it is readable you will find it much easier to find these simple typos.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a comma after `Statut`:

```
case H.Status
when 0 then ''
when 1 then 'Non Traité'
when 2 then 'Intervention'
when 3 then 'Rép. en Instance'
when 4 then 'Rép. en cours'
when 5 then 'Liv. en Instance'
when 6 then 'Liv. en cours'
when 7 then 'Email envoyé'
when 8 then 'Pickup Magasin'
when 9 then 'Arrivé a IRC'
when 10 then 'Transfert au CTA'
when 11 then 'Retour du CTA'
when 12 then 'Retour au magasin'
when 13 then 'Livraison'
end as Statut
[No_ Document Externe] as [Num_ Document Externe],
```

You need to have a comma after all the command names you have. As about the `[]` wrapped around column names, you are correct in using them, see https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-write-sql-queries-with-spaces-in-column-names/

EDIT

This is a query where the commas were added in between your fields in the `select` clause:

```
select
concat ([Document No_],[Line No_]) as [InterventionLigne],
case H.Status
when 0 then ''
when 1 then 'Non Traité'
when 2 then 'Intervention'
when 3 then 'Rép. en Instance'
when 4 then 'Rép. en cours'
when 5 then 'Liv. en Instance'
when 6 then 'Liv. en cours'
when 7 then 'Email envoyé'
when 8 then 'Pickup Magasin'
when 9 then 'Arrivé a IRC'
when 10 then 'Transfert au CTA'
when 11 then 'Retour du CTA'
when 12 then 'Retour au magasin'
when 13 then 'Livraison'
end as Statut,
[No_ Document Externe] as [Num_ Document Externe],
H.[Nom],
H.[Adresse Contact],
H.[Ville],
[Commentaire],
[Sources Réclamations],
[Date Reclamation],
[Designation],
case H.Saved
when 0 then 'Non'
when 1 then 'Oui'
end as Enregist,
case H.Validated
when 0 then 'Non'
when 1 then 'Oui'
end as Validé,
[USER] as [Utilisateur],
case H.[Type Intervention]
when 0 then ''
when 1 then 'Direct'
when 2 then 'Via Un Partenaire'
end as [Type_Intervention],
[Partenaire],[Année garantie], case H.NonEdit
when 0 then 'Non'
when 1 then 'Oui'
end as [NonEdit],
[Magasin],[Emplacement],[En Garantie],[Job No_],[Document No_] as [Document Num_],
[Line No_] as[Line Num_],
[Type Travaux],[Starting Date] as [DateDébut],
[Travaux effectués],
[Libellé],
l.[technicien],
[Remarque],
[Rémunération]
from [dbo].[Header$] H left join [dbo].[Line$] L
on H.[No_ Document]=L.[Document No_]
```

Please let me know if it is working better for you now.

Comment: thank you but it still tells that the columns are not valid do you have any idea?

Comment: @IbtissamFethani please update your question with your current query and error and let me know here in the comment section.

Comment: I think this answer is correct.

Comment: Downvote is likely because you did not actually **fix** the code causing the error. You wrote "need to have a comma" but you did not demonstrate that in the code you included. The link you mentioned is also not relevant as far as I can tell.

Comment: @SMor thanks for the reply. I have added such a query to my answer.